# Why doesn't Stack Apps have community promotion ads?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

Community Promotion Ads would enable Stack App developers to promote their apps to other members of the Stack Apps community. Do we need community promotion ads or not?

Comment: Probably because it's low traffic and a bit of a "special" site -- not strictly Q&A like the other sites.  ... **See also:**  [When does a site get Community Promotion Ads?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251219/when-does-a-site-get-community-promotion-ads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community promotion ads wouldn't promote apps.

These ads exist to promote sites as a whole.  If you wish to put such ads on other sites, then there is nothing to stop you posting proposals on their meta sites.  Most sites have a post that calls for ads, just answer it and see if your proposal is accepted by them.

Looking at it the other way, the StackApps site doesn't really need to display community ads for other StackExchange sites.  People who come here often know what the other sites are.